# Javascript single backslash in string variable not working

Tags: javascript, html, variables, web, web-deployment

I am sending a string variable from spring boot controller to JavaScript and my string is basically a file path with single backslash. I am reading the path in JavaScript but it is ready single backslash as a escape character or something.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var path = "S:\\CD\2020\ABCDEF"
    alert(path)
</script>
```

The output I am getting is S:\CD‚0ABCDEF in the alert

I want "S:\CD\2020\ABCDEF"

Answer (score 1):

You need to do

```
var path = "S:\\CD\\2020\\ABCDEF"
```

a backslash is an escape character so you need to escape the backslash.

If you don't control it, try to use `String.raw` like so:

```js
alert(String.raw`S:\\CD\2020\ABCDEF`)
```

Comment: I am getting this variable from spring boot controller and I have no control over this variable. I cant directly change it.

Comment: You could try using `String.raw`, see edit

Comment: is there any way to use replace function and replace single backslash with double backslash?

Comment: The issue is that the string itself doesn't actually have the backslash once it's in the variable, you need to get at it *before* it "becomes" a variable

Comment: String.raw also does not work, now its now showing the alert

Answer (score 1):

**In JavaScript `\` is an escape character used to denote the beginning of special sequences.**

These sequences include `\n`, `\t` and even Unicode characters. When you want to use the `\` character on its own, write two like this `\\`.

**So in your case:**

- We can use [`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) to stop JavaScript from parsing escape sequences.
- And also [`.replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) to change all occurrences of the `\\` sequence.

```js
var path = String.raw`S:\\CD\2020\ABCDEF`

let singular = (String.raw`\a`).slice(0, 1)
let double = String.raw`\\`

path = path.replaceAll(double, singular)

alert(path)
```

**As a function:**

```js
function getString() {
   return String.raw `S:\\CD\2020\ABCDEF`
} // This function can be replaced with the function you are using to get the path from the user.

function replaceEscapes(rawString) {
  let singular = (String.raw `\a`).slice(0, 1)
  let double = String.raw `\\`

  return rawString.replaceAll(double, singular)
}

alert(
  replaceEscapes(getString())
)
```

Comment: I am getting this variable from spring boot controller and I have no control over this variable. I cant directly change it.

Comment: is there any way to use replace function and replace single backslash with double backslash?

Comment: @MutahirKiani I've made an edit to my post, this should let you replace the characters programmatically.

Comment: Thanks man this solved my problem. Have a nice day :)

Comment: @MutahirKiani No problem , If it worked make sure to mark the solution as accepted.

Comment: I am sorry I cant make it because I have only 13 reputations. People with more than 15 reputations can vote.

Answer (score 1):

`\` is used to escape characters. Add an extra `\` to get past it:

```js
var path = "S:\\C\\2020\\ABCDEF"
    alert(path)
```

Comment: I am getting this variable from spring boot controller and I have no control over this variable. I cant directly change it.

Comment: Change it in your front end right? Make a copy and add extra `\`. Is that not possible?

Comment: is there any way to use replace function and replace single backslash with double backslash?